# The sequence $a_n=\frac{2n+1}{(n-1)^2}$ decreases monotonically

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, inequality

How could we show that the sequence $a_n=\frac{2n+1}{(n-1)^2}$ decreases monotonically?

When we take the quotient $\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}$ we get $\frac{n^2(2n+1)}{(n-1)^2(2n+3)}$. Howcan we conclude that this quotient is $\geq 1$ ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alternatively, one may write it as the sum of two decreasing sequences:
$$
\frac{2n+1}{(n-1)^2}=\frac{2(n-1)+3}{(n-1)^2}=\frac{2}{n-1}+\frac{3}{(n-1)^2},\qquad n\ge 2.
$$

Comment: Ah ok... We have also that $a_n$ is a zero-sequence. From Leibniz criterium we have then that the series $\displaystyle{\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{2n+1}{(n-1)^2}(-1)^n}$ converges, right? If we have the series $\displaystyle{\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{2n+1}{(n-1)^2}}$ what criterium should we use to check the convergence?

Comment: @MaryStar Yes by Leibniz criterium, you obtain the convergence of the alternate series.

Comment: @MaryStar On the other hand, we have $\dfrac{2n+1}{(n-1)^2} \ge  \dfrac{3}{n-1}$, $n\ge2$, and $\displaystyle{\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{3}{n-1}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{3}{n}$ is divergent.

Comment: I see!! If we had the series $\displaystyle{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})}$ and $\displaystyle{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})}$, would we use for the first one again the Leibniz criterium and for the second one again the comparison criterium?

Comment: @MaryStar Yes, by observing that $\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}=\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}$.

Comment: For the first series,to use the Leibniz criterium, we have to show again that $a_n=\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}$ is monotonically decreasing. Do we quotient or the difference of $a_{n+1}$ and $a_n$ ? For the second series, having that $\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}=\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}$, can we do the following? $$\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}<2\sqrt{n+1}<2(n+1)$$ Therefore $$\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}=\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}>\frac{1}{2(n+1)}$$ Do we use again the harmonic series here?

Comment: For the first one, why not just observe that $n \mapsto \sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}\ge 1$ is increasing, giving that $n \mapsto 1(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})$ is decreasing. For the second series, it's OK.

Comment: Not really, $\sum_{n=1}^N\frac1{n+1}=\sum_{n=2}^{N+1}\frac1n$ by a change of index, hence we conclude to the divergence.

Comment: Doesn't the first sum starts from 0 and so we get $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$ ?

Comment: Both series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$ and $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$ are divergent...

Comment: Ah ok.... For the first one, how do we know that $\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}$ is increasing?

Comment: The derivative of $\sqrt{x}$: is $\frac1{2\sqrt{x}}>0$.

Comment: I understand!! Thank you very much!! :-)

Comment: @Mary Star You are welcome.

Answer (score 5):

or we compute $$a_{n+1}-a_n=\frac{2n+3}{n^2}-\frac{2n+1}{(n-1)^2}=-{\frac {2\,{n}^{2}+4\,n-3}{{n}^{2} \left( n-1 \right) ^{2}}}<0$$ since we have $n>0$

Comment: I see!! Thank you!! :-)

Answer (score 3):

$\frac{n^2(2n+1)}{(n-1)^2(2n+3)}>1 \iff 2n^3+n^2>(n^2-2n+1)(2n+3) \iff 2n^3+n^2>2n^3+3n^2-4n^2-6n+2n+3 \iff 2n^2+4n-3>0 \iff (\sqrt{2}n+\sqrt{2})^2-5>0 \iff (\sqrt{2}n+\sqrt{2})^2>5$

Since the last inequality true and we have only biconditionals, it follows that the first inequality, which is precisely what we want, is correct. Therefore the method is basically using what we want to prove. However, keep in mind that you cannot use $\implies$ for once because then you cannot work backwards.

Comment: I see!! Thank you!! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Every term of the sequence is positive. So, the sequence is decreasing if, and only if, the ratio $a_{n+1}/a_{n} < 1$ for every integer $n \geq 2$.
\begin{equation*}
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}} = \frac{(2n+3)(n-1)^2}{(2n+1)n^{2}} = \frac{(2n+3)(n^{2} - 2n + 1)}{2n^{3} + n^{2}}
= \frac{2n^{3} - n^{2} - 4n + 3}{2n^{3} + n^{2}} .
\end{equation*}
For every integer $n \geq 2$,
\begin{equation*}
2n^{2} + 4n - 3 = \left(n + 2 - \sqrt{\frac{5}{2}}\right)\left(n + 2 + \sqrt{\frac{5}{2}}\right) > 0 .
\end{equation*}
So,
\begin{equation*}
2n^{3} - n^{2} - 4n + 3 < 2n^{3} + n^{2} ,
\end{equation*}
and $a_{n+1}/a_{n} < 1$.